# Flutter deep link adb local testing error

Tags: android, flutter, deep-linking

Im getting the following error after trying to test my deeplinks for android locally using the adb.

```bash
adb shell 'am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW \                                          52s
    -c android.intent.category.BROWSABLE \
    -d "http://courtyard.gg/"' \
    gg.courtyard.courtyard_mobile
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW cat=[android.intent.category.BROWSABLE] dat=http://courtyard.gg/... pkg=gg.courtyard.courtyard_mobile }
Error: Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW cat=[android.intent.category.BROWSABLE] dat=http://courtyard.gg/... flg=0x10000000 pkg=gg.courtyard.courtyard_mobile }
```

I followed along every step of the [flutter docs for deep links](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/set-up-app-links) and Im now trying to test it locally.

My app runs three different flavors with different dart entry points, is there any extra configuration needed for that?

This is my main activity tag

```xml
<application
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:exported="true"
            android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- Deep Linking -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="flutter_deeplinking_enabled"
                android:value="true" />
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="courtyard.gg"
                    android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />

    </application>
```

Comment: see one of my answers for deep link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75092734/flutter-deep-linking-is-not-working-in-cold-state/75093156#75093156

Comment: I have the same config than u. Im trying to test it with the adb to see if its working, do you know how to do that correctly? Btw im not using unilinks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found out the package name is not:

> the package property under  tag

as the flutter docs specify.

It is by default if you don't have flavors in your app, but in case you have, your *"package_name"* will be the *"application id"* of your flavor. More about that here [ApplicationId versus PackageName - Android Studio Project Site](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename)

In case you don't know what your package name is you can follow these steps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74617502/13592374

Be aware that in this last link, many answers mention that to launch your app from the adb shell you can use commands like:

```bash
adb shell am start -n com.package.name/com.package.name.ActivityName
```

For this to work with flavors the correct nomenclature would be:

```bash
adb shell am start -n flavor.app.id/manifest.package.name.ActivityName
```

Hope this helps anyone in the same situation!